# Launching Android App from through url from Chrome browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, android-webview

I wish to open android app on click of the url .

The idea is the link will open in browser and look for the package and launch the application or redirect to app store.

From the Chrome documentation , i can see that we cannot launch app directly without user interaction.

Is there any way we can achieve this functionality.

I took implementation from this

https://github.com/danielgindi/app-redirect

This works but from the  diclaimer mentioned copying the link in chrome browser does not launch the app.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

And Chrome doesn’t launch an external app for a given Intent URI in the following cases.

When the Intent URI is redirected from a typed in URL.
When the Intent URI is initiated without user gesture

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about Firebase Dynamic Links? See here if this is what you are searching for: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: Firebase dynamic links are deprecated and shouldn't be used in the new projects